# How to make two way slider bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, slider, range

I just want to make the seekbar as shown in the image. How can I achieve this?

[image: Slider]

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for this, to no avail. So I made a new widget, feel free to use it: https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/
This will work for sure! just go to this address and copy the code and make the class.